# A classification machine learning flow chart implimenting dimentionality reduction, upsampling, and cross validation

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, pca, smote

I would like to make a flow chart for an ML classifier and make sure that my thinking is correct.

Here is a little about my sample:
I have 3 classes and about 160 features. I suspect that some of those features are redundant.
My classes are imbalanced.
Please let me know if I should provide more info about the sample.

This is my first try on tackling a machine learning problem. Based on checking the functionality of each of the options I use below, I chose it in that specific order, but i might be wrong.

Could someone just let me know if this flow chart is logical, and if there was a problem in any of the step, could you possible tell me why it is not supposed to be there?

Flow chart

1. Get the data
2. Make it in a readable format and import it
3. Split the data into train/test
4. Standardize with StandardScalar
5. Perform PCA on train data
6. Perform K-fold cross-validation on train data
7. Apply SMOTE
8. Predict (Using SVC)
9. Make a confusion matrix
10. Perform GridSearchCV
11. Perform PermutationImportance

Comment: The flow chart you have given looks complete to me.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, wanted to know if it is in proper order.

Comment: Just got a note that the standardization should happen on the data that is already split to avoid data leakage..
Still need a confirmation.